# Using recursion in nested dictionaries?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to flatten a nested dictionary in python 2.7x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490963/how-to-flatten-a-nested-dictionary-in-python-2-7x)

If I have a dictionary:

```
dictionaryname= { 'key1' : 'value1',
                     'key2' : 'value2',
                     'key3' : { 'key3a': 'value3a' },
                     'key4' : { 'key4a': { 'key4aa': 'value4aa',
                                           'key4ab': 'value4ab',
                                           'key4ac': 'value4ac'},
                                'key4b': 'value4b'}
                   }
```

How do I make it so that the result would be as follows:

```
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
key3a
value3a
...
```

I just have to print whole dictionary, not necessarily in the right order.

If I use:

```
def print_all(dictionaryname):
    for i in dictionaryname:
        print i
```

I only get:

```
key1
key2
key3
...
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_all(d):
    if isintance(d, dict):
        for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
            print k
            print_all(v)
    else:
        print d
```

Answer (score 4):

I came up with:

```
def printdict(d):
    for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
        print key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            printdict(value)
        else:
            print value
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to flatten the structure using a function:

```
def flatten(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        yield k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for subitem in flatten(v):
                yield subitem
        else:
            yield v
```

then use that to loop over your structure:

```
for item in flatten(dictionaryname):
    print item
```

Python dictionaries are not ordered, so the output will not be sorted or matching the order in which you declared your structure.

Version without `yield`:

```
def flatten(d, res=None):
    if res is None:
        res = []
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        res.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten(v, res)
        else:
            res.append(v)
    return res
```

Both versions print:

```
>>> for item in flatten(dictionaryname):
...     print item
... 
key3
key3a
value3a
key2
value2
key1
value1
key4
key4a
key4ab
value4ab
key4ac
value4ac
key4aa
value4aa
key4b
value4b
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am not allowed to use yield..I shoud've mentioned that that's a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

One funny but not very "proper" way would be converting the dictionary to a json string and play with the splitting.